# Azure Function App with Multiple Runtimes?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How to I install multiple runtimes in an Azure Function App?

I have a Python 3.7 app that uses a Java app whilst running. I have the Java runtime installed locally (in Windows 10) and, using VS Code, the Function App runs fine locally. I have created a Function App in Azure (Python 3) and published the app to the Azure Function App. Unsurprisingly, it doesn't work because there's no Java runtime installed in the Function App. Is there a way to create an Azure Function App with multiple runtimes? (JRE and Python 3.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way worked for me: I installed the runtime using Python itself using the "install-jdk" utility: https://pypi.org/project/install-jdk/

```
import jdk

jdk.uninstall('15', jre=True)
path_to_java_home = jdk.install('15', jre=True)
```

The uninstall was needed to avoid errors when running the install.
I then used the path_to_java_home to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable and add it (appended with /bin) to the path.